# Bootstrap javascript loaded but not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying the new Bootstrap but I have a problem with the JavaScript. I loaded it with the three lines at the end of my `<body></body>` :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And tested it with a dropdown... Which doesn't work. I'm working with Laravel and Blade, that's may be the reason, no ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Content -->
        <main class="container">
            @yield('main')
        </main>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT : I forgot, but when I'm doing `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION` in the console, I have the version number of Bootstrap, which mean that it's loaded no?

Comment: You need to share the code which you use the bootstrap.

Comment: I shared it, it's the dropdown above

Comment: What your browser console say?

Comment: Mmmmh... Nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... Everything need to be inside a `.container` even if you use only the javascript. So, this works nice now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```